# Greedy Layerwise Training with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a multi-layer perceptron in Keras (version 2.2.4-tf) that trains layers iteratively.  I've been using https://machinelearningmastery.com/greedy-layer-wise-pretraining-tutorial/ as a model, but things aren't quite working for me.  Here's my code:

```
# Train first layer
mlp = keras.models.Sequential()
mlp.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
mlp.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
mlp.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
mlp.fit(X,y)
output_layer = mlp.layers[-1]

# Add and train second layer
mlp.pop()
for layer in mlp.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
mlp.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
mlp.add(output_layer)
mlp.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
mlp.fit(X,y)
```

The error I get is

```
 ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:', array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
       0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
       1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
       0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       0., 0., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32))
```

If I try commenting out the second compile I instead get

```
ValueError: Weights for model sequential_3 have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

In case it's relevant, I'm running Keras with a Tensorflow-1.14.0 backend, installed via conda from mkl repo.

```
~ $ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/justin/.conda/envs/local_idp:
#
tensorflow                1.14.0          mkl_py36h2526735_0  
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          mkl_py36h7ce6ba3_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0
```

Many thanks,

Justin

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. The fit() method executes successfully the second time as well.

Comment: That's interesting -- thanks for testing it out Manoj.  Could you let me know which version of Keras and which backend you're using?

Comment: Keras - 2.2.4 and tensorflow - 1.14.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue. The issue is happening because of using keras from the tensorflow namespace. Replace

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

with

```
import keras
```

Comment: I especially like that you figured out my import statement without my putting it in the sample code.  Naively, I would have thought the two imports would be equivalent.  Is there any easy reference for what the difference would be?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reference. But Keras 2.2.4 was released last October. Since then many changes have happened on the master branch which have not been released. So, we have Keras 2.2.4, Keras master and tf.keras. Things may not work uniformly across these three versions.